# Vim won't load plugin?

Tags: vim

So I installed [youcompleteme](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) for vim and when running vim as sudo, everything works as expected. I get autocomplete as well as syntax-highlighting.

However when running vim as normal user, YCM does not appear to be working.
I do get syntax-highlighting but I suspect that being due to `:syntax on` in my `~/.vimrc`. I do not get the autocomplete I got from YCM when starting as sudo.

This is my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=4
let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/Documents/code'
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 0
:syntax on
:set nu
:filetype on
```

Before you ask, the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` is in fact in the specified folder.

Also here is the output of `uname -a`:
`Linux PC 5.14.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun, 10 Oct 2021 00:48:26 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

How can I get YCM's functionality as non-privileged user?

Comment: maybe your ycm directory has only root permission because you executed `sudo` while installing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after some trying I found the following:
it looks like I made a blunder. After putting
`let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/Documents/code/.ycm_extra_config.py'` in my `.vimrc` it was fixed.

All it needed was the full path, including the filename.